# TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword for this function. What could be?

Tags: io, python-3.6

This line throws the exception:

```
with open(output_file_path, mode='w', enconding='utf-8') as output_file:
```

I run my script with `python` which returns 3.6 when I run `python --version`. Also running it with `python3 <script>` throws the same.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open) says it should work

Comment: What is the output of printing `open`?

Comment: `>>> print(open) <built-in function open>`

Comment: In your script, not the REPL.

Comment: It prints the same `<built-in function open>` then the Traceback, so its not overriden or redefined

Comment: You've written `enconding` instead of `encoding`.